# " nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near '?' "

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc, sybase

I'm trying to execute a SQL statement in my Java application via the `JdbcTemplate` of Spring Framework. I am getting a `"bad SQL grammar"` error despite the query working 100% fine in Aqua Data Studio.

Here is my Java code:

```
String entity = GCEnvironmentClient.getGteProperties().getProperty("ENTITY_ID");

InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("sql/blotter.sql");

    String query = IOUtils.toString(is).concat(entity);

    return this.jdbcTemplate.query(query, new BlotterTradeMapper());
```

One thing to note: I tried making my `RowMapper` class (`BlotterTradeMapper`) return `null` objects to avoid manipulating the `ResultSet`. This didn't change anything, so I know this class isn't causing issues.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
    inv..trans.com_line1,
    inv..trans.trade_acct,
    inv..trans.bs_code,
    inv..trans.trans_type,
    inv..trans.cust_num,
    mast..sec_mst.sec_type,
    mast..sec_mst.mature_date,
    mast..sec_mst.coupon,
    inv..trans.trans_num,
    inv..trans.trade_date,
    inv..trans.cc_code,
    inv..trans.settle_date,
    inv..trans.other_chrg,
    inv..trans.principal,
    inv..trans.interest,
    inv..trans.basis_prc,
    inv..trans.dollar_prc,
    inv..trans.quantity,
    inv..trans.cusip,
    inv..trans.rem_line1,
    inv..trans.rem_line2,
    mast..sec_mst.dated_date,
    mast..sec_mst.des_line1,
    mast..groupmst.group_name,
    mast..groupmst.group_id,
    mast..cust_mst.nam_add1,
    inv..trans.fin_rate,
    ISNULL(mast..contract.contract_size, 1),
    ISNULL(mast..contract.contract_size, 1),
    mast..curr_mst.multiplier,
    mast..sec_mst.sec_class
FROM 
    inv..trans,
    mast..sec_mst,
    mast..cust_mst,
    mast..groupmst,
    mast..curr_mst,
    mast..contract
WHERE 
    inv..trans.cust_num = mast..cust_mst.cust_num 
AND 
    inv..trans.group_id = mast..groupmst.group_id 
AND 
    inv..trans.cusip = mast..sec_mst.cusip 
AND 
    mast..sec_mst.currency_type = mast..curr_mst.currency_type
AND 
    mast..sec_mst.contract_code *= mast..contract.contract_code
AND
    inv..trans.entity_id = 1
```

Here is the error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [query]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near '?'. at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:237)
```

Note that there are no question marks in the query! Has anyone seen something like this before?

Comment: Is it normal the construct like this in Sybase : inv..trans.com_line1 ? In other SQL that I know of, we use the single point like inv.trans.com_line1

Comment: `mast..sec_mst.contract_code *= mast..contract.contract_code` is that `*` supposed to be there?

Comment: The notation is [database]..[table].[column] - this is necessary because I am pulling data from multiple databases.           @Powerlord yes that's correct. The query works 100% fine in my external SQL client Aqua Data Studio

Comment: Have you checked trace level logs for `org.springframework.jdbc` to verify that the correct query is actually performed?

Comment: Are you sure there should be a star * in "mast..sec_mst.contract_code *= mast..contract.contract_code AND inv..trans.entity_id = 1"

Comment: @Mudassar that is sybase specific join syntax. Oracle has similar syntax in addition to ANSI joins.

Comment: Are you sure that's where the error is happening?  Are you using prepared statements at all elsewhere?

Comment: @Dan I'm not using PreparedStatement - all queries are plain String objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some hidden characters at the top of the .sql file. These must have been created by Aqua Data Studio. Not even Notepad++ picked them up - only Eclipse text editor did.